# Move state change function into a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm new to React functional components, and working with some MUI code. I have this code, edited for brevity:

```
  const [userMenuAnchorEl, setUserMenuAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleUserMenuOpen = (event) => {
    setUserMenuAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };
```

```
  <MenuItem onClick={handleUserMenuOpen}>
```

```
  <UserMenu anchorEl={userMenuAnchorEl} handleClose={handleUserMenuClose}/>
```

And then a corresponding component defined in a separate file.

```
function UserMenu({anchorEl, handleClose}) {
    
    const isUserMenuOpen = Boolean(anchorEl);

    return (
      <Menu
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={isUserMenuOpen}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    );
  }

  export default UserMenu;
```

It seems to me that the `handleUserMenuOpen` function should be moved into the component. It seems in a class component that would be pretty straightforward, but I haven't been able to find the way for a functional component.

(The code is mostly pulled from [this example](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/#app-bar-with-a-primary-search-field))

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Can you explain the behavior?

Comment: The code works fine as it is. I'm trying to find out if it is possible to define `handleUserMenuOpen` in `UserMenu` instead of in the containing code, and then reference it in the containing code.

Comment: the click event handler you can pass in as props or define in the functional component. both will work. but if you are passing objects as props, better to have useCallback hook otherwise function reference will change on each render and can cause unwanted rendering.

Comment: If I define it in the functional component (that's what I'm interested in), how do  I attached it here `<MenuItem onClick={handleUserMenuOpen}>`?

Comment: Sorry I'm little confused here. so you are trying to define event handler in parent component or child component? if you are trying to define handler in child and trying to attach in parent its not possible.

Comment: "if you are trying to define handler in child and trying to attach in parent its not possible."
-
Thanks. That's really the answer to my question. So that approach is not idiomatic when using functional components.

If the component were a class, I could define a function on the class in addition to `render()` that would be the handler. I wanted to see if there was some way to do that with functional components that I missed, but I suppose it is just not an encouraged pattern.